# Boutros Boutros-Ghali reference in Seinfeld

Tags: plot-explanation, reference, seinfeld

In the episode [The Hamptons](http://seinfeld.wikia.com/wiki/The_Hamptons) of *Seinfeld* when they see George's girlfriend topless each character expresses their surprise in a different way. Jerry goes like this: *Boutros Boutros-Golly!*

Why did he use [Boutros Boutros Ghali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boutros_Boutros-Ghali) as an expression? Was there any significance behind it?

The scene in the question:

Comment: Seinfeld is full of random and obscure reference humor.

Comment: IMHO is just some irreverent wordplay. Jerrys line is a parallel structure to Kramer's line, where "Yo Yo...Ma" has Ma as the unexpected bit, and Jerry inverts to having Boutros be the unexpected bit, and Ghali/Golly is the reveal/punch.

Comment: I actually think Jerry says __"Ghali"__, the correct name, just like Kramer says __"[Yo-Yo Ma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yo-Yo_Ma)"__ - They are both using the names of _real_ people (that sound kinda funny) to express amazement.

Comment: I agree with the above:  "Yo Yo Ma" => "Mo' Mo' ... Man!" // "Boutros Boutros-Ghali" => "Boob Boob ... Golly!"

Comment: Just part of the [long tradition](https://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2016/02/16/boutros-boutros-ghali-dead_n_9243306.html) (okay — brief tradition) of Western comedians finding his name funny.

Answer (score 6):

Using repeated names is meant to evoke two similar (and nice, judging by the tone) breasts while getting past censors.

"Nice racks!" gives it away ;)

Comment: This is exactly the answer.

Answer (score -3):

Yo Yo Ma is a cellist.  And Boutros Boutros-Ghali was a general or something for Egypt I believe and a member of the UN in the later 90s.  Their references, although seeming obscure now,  are usually indicative of headline news at the time. Like the Salman Rushdie episode.  Popular news at the time.

Comment: He was a minister but not in the army (while in Egypt) if I properly recall, then secretary of the UN.